# h:dataTable header facet does not display value from row

Tags: jsf, datatable, header, facet

I'm trying to understand why the second column facet, with #{entry.value} doesn't display anything, just an empty header?

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.entries}" var="entry">
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="UserId" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{entry.key}" />
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{entry.value}" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{entry.value}" />
</h:column>
```

I've understand that maybe I'm doing it wrong, because myfaces cannot know from which row it should take the value #{entry.value} to put in the header column.

In my case each row have the same value of #{entry.value} so any rows could be ok.

So how can I have a dataTable that retrieve a list of objects (the corresponding rows) and a single value to put in a header object? (or a list of values to put in all the columns of the header) ?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Which row exactly should it show in the header?

Comment: You see the table has  two columns. The second column has a header as the first row and a value in the second row. They should display the same information , but I get an empty header ! The second row displays correctly the value of {entry.value}

Comment: You're referring a row based value in the column header. Which row exactly do you want to show the value for? Imagine that the table has 10 rows (i.e. `#{bean.entries}` returns 10 items). Which one exactly do you want to redisplay in header? (I hope you'll by now start to realize that the `<h:dataTable>` itself has exactly this problem and that's why the header is empty)

Comment: Oh I see... Hmmm that's could be the error

Comment: So let's say that beans.entries retrieve a list of 10 elements, and I want to copy in the header the third element

Comment: Then reference exactly that element via `#{bean}` instead. This only indicates a broken/brittle model. What if there are only 2 elements? You may want to step back to the whiteboard first.

Comment: Hmmm, and what if I want to copy just an element of the returned list in one column header, i mean I don't want the entire row copied in the header ,but in just a colmn of the header I want the n-th element of the list, specified an attribute ... I'm still confused

Comment: That part is easy, but you're not terribly clear on which row exactly you want to show in the column header and why exactly. Usually, a table doesn't work like that. The column header should represent a description of the column, e.g. "Name", "Email", "Title", "Price", etc. In your specific case, "Key" and "Value" would be candidate headers for those two columns. Note that this is not a JSF problem, but just a general model/design problem as to tabular data. You'd have exactly the same problem when trying the same in any other presentation framework.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To give you an example, imagine that the table show numbers, quantity of something, so sometimes the table retrieves all rows containing very small numbers, sometimes it retrieves very big numbers, so I'd like to change the header column text based on the returned data. So I was thinking to have a sort of hidden extra column, with the unit measure, and copy that value in the header column, so that's why every row contains the same value, I could copy that from any different row... Is it clear?

Comment: This is what @BalusC states in _"Then reference exactly that element via `#{bean}`"_ do a `#{bean.entries[0].uom` in the header. Works perfectly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [h:dataTable "var" attribute doesn't work inside facet EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118562/hdatatable-var-attribute-doesnt-work-inside-facet-el)